# jquery-rails how to specify jquery version

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using gem 'jquery-rails' v v4.0.5 in a Rails 4 app.
I'm also using gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', '~> 3.3.0'.

DataTables is giving me an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in isArraylike @ jquery.self-
```

I have looked up the error and it's because I'm using jquery v 1.11.3

If I look at jquery-rails/lib/jquery/rails/version

```
module Jquery       
  module Rails     
    VERSION = "4.0.5"     
    JQUERY_VERSION = "1.11.3"     
    JQUERY_2_VERSION = "2.1.4"     
    JQUERY_UJS_VERSION = "1.1.0"       
  end     
end
```

How can I get the gem to use a different version of jquery?

Comment: Which version you'd like to use?

Comment: Update  your jquery-rails version? I mean, if you use the gem, you get the version of jQuery they bundle. You could always just use your own jQuery assets.

Comment: Downgrading to jQuery 1.11.2 has worked for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locked on gem 'jquery-rails',  '4.0.4'

Answer (score 0):

I face a similar issue while rails, ruby  upgrade from rails 4.1.8 to rails 5.2.1.
Datatable started throwing an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

Found that jquery-rails got updated to latest(jquery-rails (4.3.3)) through gem file and datatables was in a asset folder without update.

Changed to datatables (1.10.19). Fixed.

So if you face the issue check for datatables release and their jquery supported version https://cdn.datatables.net/releases.html

For example https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.1/

- Update: To jQuery 1.11.1
- Fix: Compatiblity with jQuery 1.7.x